# I am sending json data to api but getting unicode json data whe api call from android device

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

My data -:

```
{"op":"merge","merge_bcards_ids":{"data":[216,217]},"target_bacard_id":226}
```

In view file I am getting json list data request.data["merge_bcards_ids"] :-

```
[258, 259] <type 'list'> which is showing correct.
```

But when this api call from external device then :-

```
[257,258] <type 'unicode'>
```

So I want list instead of unicode. Please help me out.

My view is :-

```
class BusinessViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
   queryset = BusinessCard.objects.all()
   serializer_class = BusinessCardSerializer

   def create(self, request):
       try:
          op = request.data["op"]
       except:             
          op = None

       if op == 'merge':
              try:
                 merge_bcards_ids = request.data["merge_bcards_ids"]
                 target_bacard_id = request.data["target_bacard_id"]
              except:
                 merge_bcards_ids = None
                 target_bacard_id = None
              print merge_bcards_ids   
              print merge_bcards_ids.__class__
```

Comment: Can you show me your views?

Comment: yes I have edited the question.

Comment: Sounds like the client is where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

request params are strings.

You may dump you dictionary (`json.dumps`) and sent it as a request param. 
On other side you must to use `json.loads` to convert you data back to dict.

Also you can dump only array `"data":json.dumps([216,217])` and then load it as array: `json.loads(request.data["merge_bcards_ids"])`.

It may cause some encoding/decoding errors (it depends on version of python you are using)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the data is coming as unicode, I also passed through this same situation once and i solved by converting from unicode data to normal;
This code may help you to do that;

```
if isinstance(request.data['merge_bcards_ids'], unicode):
    merge_bcards_ids = list(unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', request.data['merge_bcards_ids']).encode('ascii','ignore'))
else:
    merge_bcards_ids = request.data['merge_bcards_ids']
```

**OR**

```
merge_bcards_ids = [unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', ids).encode('ascii','ignore') for ids in list(unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', request.data['merge_bcards_ids']).encode('ascii','ignore'))).encode('ascii','ignore')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the "application/json" content type when submitting your request.